# HTTP GET, then GET again in Express leads to undefined error, on first GET page

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

Simply, open a form, form has a link to a list, but instead of the list, I get "id" undefined, as an error for the form we CAME from, that already works.

I have a GET page, to present a form, to modify the record at /locations/:id
The form works, I can submit it, and POST the results, save them, all that works. 
Once I GET the form, it has four links on it, to GET (hence the again) all of the "machines" or "collectors" etc, at the location with "id" (mongoose object _id) we are currently modifying. Clicking the only link I've written the controller for, results in an error stating that "id" on the form we just came from, that used "id" to load in the first place, is undefined. List of locations >> form to modify one of them >> new page (target _blank) to display the machines present at that location.

The link to the working form:

```
<a href="/Locations/modify/<%=locations[i]._id %>"
```

The first (working) GET controller:

```
exports.loc_modify_get = function(req, res, next) {
req.sanitize('id').escape();
req.sanitize('id').trim();

async.parallel({

location: function(callback) {
  Locations.findById(req.params.id)
  .exec(callback);
},
location_list: function(callback) {
  Locations.find()
  .exec(callback);
},
route_list: function(callback) {
  SuperRoutes.find()
  .exec(callback);
},
taxareas_list: function(callback) {
  TaxAreas.find()
  .exec(callback);
}
}, function(err, results) {
console.log(results._id);
 res.render('pages/modify-loc.ejs', {
  user : req.user,
  location : results.location,
  locations : results.location_list,
  routes : results.route_list,
  taxareas: results.taxareas_list,
  id: req.params.id
  });
});
};
```

From that page is the link

```
 <a href="/location/<%=id %>/machines" target="_blank">
```

And, its' broken GET controller

```
exports.loc_machines_get = function (req, res, next) {

  async.series({

    location: function(callback) {
      Locations.findById(req.params.id)
      .exec(callback);
    },

  }, function (err, results) {
    Machines.find({machine_loc:results.location.Loc_ID}, //here
     'machine_id machine_serial machine_name machine_date machine_class',
    function(err, machines) {
      if (err) {return next(err);}
      res.render('pages/modify-loc.ejs', {
       location : results.location.Loc_Name,
       machines: machines
     });
   }); // to here, needs fixed.
 });
}
```

The resulting error (The relevant parts):

```
ReferenceError:  
<form action="/locations/Modify/<%=id %>" method="post" name="form">
id is not defined at eval
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. I was trying to render the page I just came from. modify-loc.ejs should have been loc-machines.ejs